# Decoding TCP packets as RTP in Wireshark

Tags: tcp, udp, wireshark, rtp, webrtc

I'm troubleshooting a WebRTC video calling problem in my app and i'm using Wireshark.

One end of my video call is a web app running in my browser window and the other end is a Unity based app on an Android device. This is built with WebRTC. In wireshark I could see UDP packets coming through and I was able to decode them as RTP packets this seemed to work a treat. However, I'm looking at some calls now that appear to be sending the packets through TCP. I tried to do the same decode as... as before with the UDP packets but it doesn't work. Am I coming at this the wrong way? I had entered both the sending port and the receiving port in the Decode as... window.

Any help is massively appreciated on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the 'Decode as...' window wrong. I was changing the Field column to RTP whereas I should have changed the Current column to RTP. It is now decoding my packets properly.